# How to run HTML project from github?

Tags: javascript, html, github

Sorry for the noob questions but I can't figure this particular case out. I want to try out https://github.com/albertobeta/AffectiveSlider. So decided to import the project into Eclipse.

Q1) In general how and where can I open and run thing GitHub project?

Q2) I tried importing the project in Eclipse but could not run anything or any file JS file to run.

Comment: THIS IS NOT JAVA CODE

Comment: Q1) In a thing called [qualtrics](https://github.com/albertobeta/AffectiveSlider/tree/master/code_implementations/qualtrics) Q2) There's JS in the [qualtrics](https://github.com/albertobeta/AffectiveSlider/tree/master/code_implementations/qualtrics) folder. BTW, JS is not Java.

Comment: There's no one-size-fits-all for this sort of thing. The code you're looking at is mainly HTML with some Javascript mixed in. Eclipse is a Java editor (different, unrelated language to Javascript) and is very unlikely to be able to do anything of use. I don't see any of the usual build tools I'm used to (autoconf, makefiles, some sort of `manage.py` or indicator of what webservice is intended, etc.), so it's not something I immediately know how to run.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Technically [Eclipse can be used for web dev](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers), though I don't know anyone that would voluntarily do so. Furthermore, it looks like it's just a static HTML site, so you could presumably host it with any server that supports static file hosting (eg. nginx, `python -m http.server`, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest opening the project in VS Code using the [live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension. You can open the repo in VS Code start the live server and open the project in `/code_implementations/html5`.

I don't know about Eclipse so I cant help you there.

Took two minutes and I have it running.

[image]